# Compose a byte by extracting specific bits of 2 different bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm playing little bit with bit manipulation in C (new to it).

I have the following example:

```
Int32 Input1
Int32 Input2

Int8 OutputByte
```

Bit 7..4 in OutputByte shall be constructed of the least significant 4 bit of Input1

Bit 3..0 in OutputByte shall be constructed of the least significant 4 bit of Input2

I'm trying it with the following 1 line:

```
OutputByte= ((Input1 & 0xF) << 4) | (Input2 & 0xF) << 0));
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks good to me, except you may need some casts. What are your inputs, and what do you get as result? - please show your actual code. (oh, and `<< 0` is of course unrewarding but otherwise harmless)

Comment: `<< 0` is pointless, though it does no harm (like +0), but other that that, the code seems fine. Keep in mind, that `int` is a signed type, so if you are printing the result in decimal you may get negative output from 2 positive inputs.

Comment: Seconding (thirding) what the other two commenters have written.  Your code looks fine; it's almost exactly what I would write.  (I'd probably leave off the `<< 0`, though.)  Is it not working for you?  How so?

Comment: Also I would recommend declaring Input1 and Input2 as `uint32_t` to clear up possible confusion induced by signed math

Comment: You'll have to specify in what way it is not working.

Comment: There is a bracket mismatch in what you posted I think - 2 extra closing brackets. Please check your original, as we can only comment about what we can see!

Comment: Show some example input and output values? Hat you expected and what you got?